# Using MS Access code in SQL by Identifing column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, iif

I'm using this code in Microsfot Access and get the correct results:

```
SELECT tbl_Test.generate_query AS Query Name, 
       Sum(IIf([RecNum] Is Not Null,1,0)) AS Attempts, 
       Sum(IIf([Query_test]='Yes',1,0)) AS Successes, 
       Sum(IIf([Query_test]='No',1,0)) AS Failures, 
       [Successes] & "/" & [Attempts] AS SuccessProportion
       FROM tbl_Test
       GROUP BY tbl_Test.generate_query
       ORDER BY tbl_Test.generate_query;
```

When I covert it to SQL - `[Successes]  + '/'  +  [Attempts] AS Proportion` fails as invalid column names:

```
SELECT generate_query AS Query_Name, 
       sum(case when RecNum is NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) AS Attempts, 
       sum(case when Query_test = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) AS Successes,
       sum(case when Query_test = 'No' then 1 else 0 end) AS Failures,
       [Successes]  + '/'  +  [Attempts] AS Proportion
       FROM tbl_TPF 
       GROUP BY generate_query 
       ORDER BY generate_query;
```

The output looks like:

```
Query Name           Attempts        Successes      Failures    SuccessProportion
First Query             1               0               1               0/1
Second Query            1               0               1               0/1
Third Query             2               1               1               1/2
Fourth Query            1               1               0               1/1
Fifth Query             1               0               1               0/1
Sixth Query             1               0               1               0/1
```

Can I use the columns that I have identified in SQL?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Tag it please. You must use the actual column names you got at you BD. It cannot know how it was named at access (if the names as different)

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.  I'm using SQL Server Management Studio and Microsoft Visual Studio

Comment: Just FYI, `sum(case when RecNum is NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end)` is a lot of superfluous code. You could simply use `COUNT(RecNum)`, Similarly you could use `COUNT(NULLIF(Query_test, 'No')) AS Successes, COUNT(NULLIF(Query_test, 'Yes')) AS Failures` to shorten your code. No performance increase, but tidier IMO.

Comment: Relational Data Base Management System in your case MS SQL. It's a good practice to tag it to differentiate from MySql, Oracle, etc.

Comment: Thanks jean and GarethD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  Q.Query_Name
       ,Q.Attempts
       ,Q.Successes
       ,Q.Failures
       ,CAST(Q.[Successes] AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '/' + CAST(Q.[Attempts] AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS Proportion
FROM (
SELECT generate_query AS Query_Name, 
       sum(case when RecNum is NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) AS Attempts, 
       sum(case when Query_test = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) AS Successes,
       sum(case when Query_test = 'No' then 1 else 0 end) AS Failures
       FROM tbl_TPF 
       GROUP BY generate_query 
     )Q
ORDER BY Q.Query_Name
```

Comment: My customer has decided that they would like to see the Proportion as a decimal now - Can this be done with the CAST call or do I have to code it a different way?